# Make computer opponent go automatically, update an array, and change players for the user's turn

Tags: javascript, html

Context: I am designing a tic tac toe game with JavaScript and HTML. I need to have 2 game modes, player v player and player v computer. I decided to call 2 separate functions if the user picks one or the other game type.

Requirements: Your program should allow the user to select one of two radio buttons:
a. Player v Player
b. Player v Computer

7. If the game is a “Player v Computer”, the Player always gets X and the Computer always gets the O
   symbol, but who moves first depends on the randomization just as it would if it was Player v Player
8. The AI isn’t really all that intelligent. The Computer simply looks for an open spot on the board and
   randomly selects one (again, using Math.random.) Again, the spot must be open – unoccupied – you
   must NOT write over a symbol if one already exists in a particular spot.

I have coded the player v player set of functions and the game play works fine. I am doubtful about modifying them for my player v computer requirement. I'm not sure where to start.

I must use onClick() within the cells of my game board. jQuery isn't allowed.

To tackle this, I have 2 functions. One is the manual player v player group of functions. The other is a player v computer group of functions. For player v computer, I am really struggling for how to update the array automatically, when it is the computer's turn, and then switch over to the user to make their move, then switch back again? Until a winner is found. The computer always gets the x assignment, but it is random who gets to start the game. Sorry for the messy code, still learning! Thanks for taking a look.

**What I tried**

- I set up console messages to trace whether the computer was x or o.
- I set up console messages to trace what the array[compBox] value was and made sure it wasn't undefined.
- I tried some innerHTML DOM scripts to update the array index with x or o.
- I set up a test to see if the starting player is x, then the code should update the array with an x
- If the starting player is o, then I can click in the game board and place an o.
- Then the player should change back to computer aka x

```js
         'use-strict';

        //declare variables here
        const boxs=document.querySelectorAll('.box');
        const statusTxt=document.querySelector('#status');
        const btnRestart=document.querySelector('#restart');
        const btnStart=document.querySelector('#start');
        const btnNewGame=document.querySelector('#newGame');

        let x = "x";
        let o = "o";
        options=["","","","","","","","",""];
        let running=false;
        let game = null;
        let player;

        //combo of wins possible that game checks for after each turn
        const win=[
          [0,1,2],
          [3,4,5],
          [6,7,8],
          [0,3,6],
          [1,4,7],
          [2,5,8],
          [0,4,8],
          [2,4,6]
        ];

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //which type of game is being played? test radio buttons...
        //run functions based on what the value ofgame is...

        btnStart.addEventListener("click", e => {
            console.log(e);
            }
        );

        //i have a hoisted variable problem
        //game = "no game radio button";
        //console.log("test game type at page load = "+game);

        //for the start of the game
        //what about when someone changes their game type?
        function checkGameType() {

            //btnPVP = document.getElementById("pvp");
            //btnPVC = document.getElementById("pvc");
            radioPVPchecked = document.getElementById("pvp").checked;
            radioPVCchecked = document.getElementById("pvc").checked;

            if (radioPVPchecked && !radioPVCchecked){
                document.getElementById("messageGame").innerHTML = "Player v Player Game!";
                console.log("player v player");
                clearCount();
                count = 0;
                game="pvp";
                //console.log("test game type at page load = "+game);

                if (game==="pvp") {
                    newGame();
                    pvp();
                };

            } else if (radioPVCchecked && !radioPVPchecked){
                document.getElementById("messageGame").innerHTML = "Player v Computer Game!";
                console.log("player v computer");
                game="pvc";
                //console.log("test game type at page load = "+game);
                //clear last game settings here! pvp settings are carrying over
                clearCount();
                count = 0;
                options=["","","","","","","","",""];
                if (game==="pvc") {
                    newGame();
                    pvc();
                };

            } else if (!radioPVPchecked && !radioPVCchecked) {
                document.getElementById("messageGame").innerHTML = "No Game Selected!";
                game="none";
                console.log("test game type at page load = "+game);
                newGame();

            }
        }//end checkGameType

        /*!! decided not to use this code
        function clearGameType() {

            radioPVPunchecked = (document.getElementById("pvp").checked = false);
            radioPVCunchecked = (document.getElementById("pvc").checked = false);
            console.log("game selection has been cleared");
            document.getElementById("messageGame").innerHTML = "Pick a game!";
            restartGame();
            game="none";
            console.log(game+" ---- New Game var test");

            }//end clearGameType
        */

        //these functions are for external to the player game play
        function newGame() {
            options=["","","","","","","","",""];
            //radioPVPunchecked = (document.getElementById("pvp").checked = false);
            //radioPVCunchecked = (document.getElementById("pvc").checked = false);
            running=true;
            boxs.forEach(box=>{
            box.innerHTML="";
            box.classList.remove('win');
            });
            counter = 0;
            stopCount();
        }

        function restartGame(){
                options=["","","","","","","","",""];

                setRandomPlayer();

                running=true;
                statusTxt.textContent='New Game! '+player+' turn!';

                boxs.forEach(box=>{
                  box.innerHTML="";
                  box.classList.remove('win');
                });
                counter = 0;
                stopCount();
        }//end of restartgame

        ///////////////////////////////
        //set up timer here so it can be accessed in funcs
        //function for game type player v player
        //game timer that looks ugly but works

        //i tried making this a nested function and it was a disaster
        let counter = 0;
        let timeout;
        let timer_on = 0;

        function timedCount() {
            document.getElementById("timeClock").innerHTML = counter+" seconds";
            counter++;
            timeout = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);
            //testing the timer in console
            //console.log(counter);
        }

        function startCount() {
            if (!timer_on) {
            timer_on = 1;
            timedCount();
            }
            //console.log(counter);
        }

        function stopCount() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timer_on = 0;
            //counter = 0;
            document.getElementById("timeClock").innerHTML = counter+" seconds";
        }

        function clearCount() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            counter = 0;
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////

        function setRandomPlayer(){
            //wow it actually works, sometimes o starts, sometimes x starts
            currentPlayer=Math.random() > 0.5 ? x : o; //images are being used not x and o
            //this needs to be fixed because it doesn't match the random player order
            //ok fixed the status message matches the current player
            player=currentPlayer;
            console.log(game+" test in func setRandomPlayer");
        }//end of random player func



        ///////// player v player function //////////////////
        ///
        ///

        function pvp() {

            function init(){
            //the system waits for user interaction - a click in the box
            boxs.forEach(box=>box.addEventListener('click',boxClick));
            btnRestart.addEventListener('click',restartGame);
            setRandomPlayer();
            statusTxt.textContent=player+"'s turn!";
            running=true;
            //console.log(game+" test in init");
            }//end of init

            init();

            console.log("if pvp func test---- "+game);

            ///////////////////////////////
            //start game play here
            function boxClick(){
                const index=this.dataset.index;
                //if
                if(options[index]!=="" || !running){
                    return;
                }
                console.log("a click is recorded here");
                updateBox(this,index);
                isWinner();
            }

            //use a button to start the game play and attach timer to that     
            //not needed ^; timer works fine onclick, finally

            function updateBox(box,index){
                options[index]=player;
                //dynamic html in the doc
                box.innerHTML=currentPlayer;
                console.log(currentPlayer+" plays their turn");
            }

            function nextPlayer(){
                player=(player==="x") ? "o" :"x";
                currentPlayer=(currentPlayer===x) ? o :x;
                statusTxt.textContent=player +"'s turn";
                console.log("next player's turn "+currentPlayer);
            }

            //did anyone win
            function isWinner(){
                let isWon=false;

                for(let i=0;i<win.length;i++){
                const condition=win[i]; //[0,1,2]
                const box1=options[condition[0]]; 
                const box2=options[condition[1]]; 
                const box3=options[condition[2]]; 
                    if(box1==="" || box2==="" || box3===""){
                      continue;
                    }
                    if(box1===box2 && box2===box3){
                      isWon=true;
                      boxs[condition[0]].classList.add('win');
                      boxs[condition[1]].classList.add('win');
                      boxs[condition[2]].classList.add('win');
                    }
                }

                if(isWon){
                    statusTxt.textContent='player '+player+' wins!!';
                    running=false;
                    //stop the timer here too
                    stopCount();

                    }else if(!options.includes("")){
                      statusTxt.textContent='The Game is Tied';
                      running=false;
                    }else{
                      nextPlayer();
                    }
                }//end of check winner

            }//end of pvp func

        ///////// player v computer function //////////////////
        ///
        ///


        function pvc() {

            function init(){
            //the system waits for user interaction - a click in the box
            boxs.forEach(box=>box.addEventListener('click',boxClick2));
            btnRestart.addEventListener('click',restartGame);
            setRandomPlayer();//who will start the game first
            statusTxt.textContent=player+"'s turn - \n\Computer = x | You = o";
            running=true;
            //console.log(game+" test in init");
            }//end of init

            init();

            //I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO THIS LOL
            console.log("CODE COMPUTER PART OF THIS GAME");

            //assign stamps to player and computer per instructions
            comp = "x";
            you = "o";

            //place the stamp on the board
            //umm
            //figure out a random box for the computer
            compBox = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);   
            compMove = options[compBox]; 

            console.log(compBox+" -- is the cell for computer"); //shows the random spaces of the options
            console.log(player+" -- is the current player"); //works
            console.log(comp+ " -- is computer"); //works
            console.log(compBox, compMove+" -- test computer array spot"); //works

            //when current turn is computer:
            //AI places a stamp
            //then it should be user's turn


            if (player === comp) {
                compMove = player;
                boxClick2();
                updateBox2();
                nextPlayer2();
            }
            //click somewhere
            if (player === you) {
                boxClick2();
                updateBox2();
                nextPlayer2();
            }

            function boxClick2(){
                //compBox=this.dataset.compBox;
                if(options[compBox]!=="" || !running){
                    return;
                }
                console.log("a move is recorded here");
                updateBox2(this,compBox);
                //isWinner();
            }

            //update the box
            function updateBox2(box){
                compMove=player;
                //dynamic html in the doc
                //box.innerHTML=player;
                console.log(player+" plays their turn");
            }

            //next players turn
            function nextPlayer2(){
                player=(player==="x") ? "o" :"x";
                currentPlayer=(currentPlayer===x) ? o :x;
                statusTxt.textContent=currentPlayer +"'s turn";
                console.log("next player's turn "+currentPlayer);
            }

        }//end of pvc play functions
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'DM Serif Display', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#timer {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#timeClock {
  text-align: center;
}

#pickGame {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#messageGame {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: blueviolet;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#status {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

button {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  border: 1px black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

button:active {
  background-color: salmon;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.win {
  animation: winAnimation ease-in-out 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes winAnimation {
  0% {
    background-color: #7c74d4;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #d8d5f5;
  }
  0% {
    background-color: #7c74d4;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<h3>What kind of game do you want to play ?</h3><br>

<input type="radio" id="pvp" name="gameType" value="Player v Player" />Player v Player
<input type="radio" id="pvc" name="gameType" value="Player v Computer" />Player v Computer<br><br>
<button id="start" onclick="checkGameType()">START!</button>
<!--<button id="newGame" onclick="newGame()">New Game</button>-->

<div id="messageGame"></div><br>

<div>----[[Game Clock]]----</div>
<p id="timeClock"> </p>
<div id="status">Pick a game above and hit Start!</div>

<div class="container" id="board">
  <div data-index="0" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="1" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="2" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="3" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="4" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="5" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="6" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="7" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="8" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="restart" onclick="restartGame()">Restart</button>

<script src="pvpgame.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It has some errors (missing startCount) for example. Please make it a [mcve]

Comment: more details wouldn't hurt the question. Nowhere in your explanation it is made clear what game you trying to program, you only can figure out from the snippet (not from the code itself) that you trying to program a tic-tac-toe game. Also, you should program cleaner. You already use eventListener, so there is no reason to still use onclick triggers especially if you need to copy that same trigger to 9 elements. An eventlistener on all those elements would be much cleaner.

Comment: after further looking through your JS, I see a lot of repetitive code. You should make the code cleaner by removing repetitive lines, making it easier to help you. Beyond that, There is no difference if you play PvP or PvE in most parts of your script. The function that checks if one player/Ai has won, is in both cases the same. Same as the function that tracks the turn of a player. Instead of programming a full function for PvP and PvE you should re-use those functions.

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for the feedback. I have to use onClick because it's required in the project. My code is definitely ugly. I am basically brand new to JavaScript. I tried to reuse my pvp funcs but I can't make sense of the logic. I am not sure how to initiate the computer player. Maybe I can use an if statement like if player is computer or if player is user... like I did for the radio buttons... and then call pvp and pvc functions within that?

Comment: ok, can you give me a full description of the project task and the requirements? I will help you to fix the logic and the code but don't want to use stuff that you are not allowed to use.

Comment: Delegate: `const boxClick = (e) => { const tgt = e.target; if (!tgt.matches(".box")) return;  
const index = tgt.dataset.index; if (options[index] !== "" || !running) return;  updateBox(tgt, index);  isWinner(); }; document.getElementById("board").addEventListener("click",boxClick); `

Comment: _"I am not sure how to initiate the computer player."_ - the computer has to make a choice, every time after the user made one - so trigger it exactly then, _when_ the user has made their choice. Where is the actual problem with that?

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for the additional review. how can I contact you?

Comment: It would not be allowed to move that whole topic outside of SO as this would help you but not the community. You can simply post the requirements of the task in your question by editing it. I can give you a detailed answer to solve the issue and address other issues.

Comment: Hi @tacoshy, thank you for helping me. I added the AI requirements to the description. I am thinking I need to do some kind of iteration for when the user wants to play the computer. Instead of "if", maybe a do while or while? So that whenever it is the computer's turn, the x should stamp on its own and then it's the user's turn again. I am trying to reuse my existing play functions but struggling with that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer but I was off my PC for the weekend and holidays.

#### What I liked about your attempt

What I really liked about your code was the way you wrote it. Constants were declared at the very top. You used more or less self-explaining names for your variables instead of shortcuts which helps with readability. Your indents were clean and sufficiently commented on. I also recognize your effort and that you really tried to solve the task yourself before posting here!

#### What I didn't like about your attempt

IMHO you missed professional planning on your project. You have a good style of writing but it is inconsistent. For example, you have variables (Which actually are constants for player `x` and `o`. But in your code, you use those variables once but the second time you decided to use strings instead of your variables. At the top, you decided to use `querySelector` for IDs, and further down you switched to `getElementById`. Some of your variable or constant names could have been more accurate or detailed. `game` for example is a variable to define the game mode or type -> It should be named as such. Last but not least your code is for the majority repetitive. While going no further into details here, those issues are majorly caused by missing planning.

#### Planning

Any good programmer will put significant effort into planning before starting to program. There is a method that is very effective as a guideline: The 7 steps of the SDLC Software Development Life Cycle.

1. Requirement Analysis
2. Defining
3. Design
4. Coding
5. Testing
6. Deployment
7. Maintenance

The Standish Group Chaos report states that nearly 2/3 of all failed projects are failing because of missing planning.

Gathering Analysis is pretty much your task while more interesting for you will be Defining. There you plan how you would solve a task and a good tool to do that would be either `Program Flow-Charts` or `Nassi-Shneiderman Diagrams`. Make a plan on how you would solve the issue on paper first before programming it:

#### Programm Logic

For the most part, you already solved the task with exception of the AI or computer move logic. But as said before your code is repetitive and redoing a lot of steps.

1. You need to check what game mode has been selected. In your attempt, you had only 2 possibilities: PvP and PvC. But there is a 3rd possibility: No Game Mode has been selected. Mean's you have to check if a game mode has been selected and output an error message if not.
2. If a game starts (and there is so far no difference between `start game`, `restart game`, or `start new game`), the board has to be initialized. This means it has to reset all the fields, variables, and counts... If you have to initialize all that anyways, why declare them at the top? Why declare that initialization resets at different places?
3. There is no difference between PvP and PvC from either the game logic, the win check logic, or the next turn logic. The only difference between PvP and PvC is, that in PvC `Player O` has to do an automated move. The easiest way to solve it is by checking if the game mode is PvC and Player O has to make a move and if that double condition is true, then roll a random move.
4. You do not need to check every round if someone won or if there is a draw. The earliest possible turn where one player could win is at turn 5. Before that, no one has made 3 moves and as such could not connect 3 cells. The only possible draw is at the end of turn 9.

#### Computer Move Logic

The requirement of your task is to have a dumb AI that not makes an educated move but simply a random move of a possible cell.

```js
let unpickedCells = [];
  
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  if (options[i] === '') {
    unpickedCells.push(i);
  }
}
```

so you create on every AI turn an array where you check the `options` array for empty cells, Then you push those empty cells (respectively their index) into that fresh array. That array of `unpickedCells` is a list of all possible available picks. Then you can use the `Mat.random` function to pick a random element from that array:

```js
unpickedCells[Math.floor(Math.random() * unpickedCells.length)]
```

That will return the index of cell that has not been picked and has to be used in your script to run the same `clickBox` function just replacing the `this.dataset.index` function.

This is not how I would have solved the whole task but reused as much of your code as possible and cut it down to the necessary part without repeating the code like you initially did:

```js
//declare variables here
const boxs = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
const statusTxt = document.querySelector('#status');
const btnRestart = document.querySelector('#restart');
const btnStart = document.querySelector('#start');
const btnNewGame = document.querySelector('#newGame');
const messageGame = document.querySelector('#messageGame');

const x = 'X';
const o = 'O';
const pvp = 'Player v Player';
const pvc = 'Player v Computer';


let options;
let running = false;
let gameType = null;
let player;
let isWon;
let currentTurn;

// I didnt reused your clock as it had nothing to do with the actual issue. You can readd it of course.
function startCount() {
  // empty function to avoid onclick trigger "Uncaught ReferenceError"
}

// What will be the difference between resratGame, ChckGameType, and newGame?
function restartGame() {
  checkGameType();
}

// Checks if a gamy mode has been selected and which one
function checkGameType() {
  let checkedGameTypeElement = document.querySelector('input[name="gameType"]:checked');
  // you missed the possiblity that no mode was selected and as such must include an error message for that case
  gameType = (checkedGameTypeElement !== null) ? checkedGameTypeElement.value : null;
  messageGame.textContent = (checkedGameTypeElement !== null) ? `${gameType} Game!` : `No Game Type has been selected`;

  // don't start directly with playing, initialize the board first!
  if (gameType !== null) {
    init();
  }
}

function init() {
  boxs.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('click', boxClick));

  running = true;
  isWon = false;
  // new variable that tracks the current turn. The function nextPlayer will increment it. So start with 0
  currentTurn = 0;

  player = Math.random() > 0.5 ? x : o;
  
  options = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
  running = true;
  boxs.forEach(box => {
    box.textContent = '';
    box.classList.remove('win');
    box.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'false');
  });
  counter = 0;
  //stopCount();
  
  nextPlayer();
}

function nextPlayer() {
  player = (player === x) ? o : x;
  statusTxt.textContent = `${player}'s turn!`;
  currentTurn++;
  
  // Check if the game mode is PvC and if it is, then run the AI logic to automate Player O 
  if (player === o && gameType === pvc) {
    boxClick();
  }
}

function boxClick() {
  // here you get the either the idnex of the clicked cell or a random index of an empty cell in case that the AI made a turn
  let clickedCellIndex = (player === o && gameType === pvc) ? AImove() : this.dataset.index;
  let clickedElement = document.querySelector(`.box[data-index="${clickedCellIndex}"]`);

  clickedElement.textContent = player;
  // aria-disabled is an attribtue same as disabled with the exception that it can be used on a non-input element such as a div. See CSS for more
  clickedElement.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
  options[clickedCellIndex] = player;
  
  // the earlist point where a palyer could win is at turn 5. No need to run the function before
  if (currentTurn >= 5) {
    isWinner();
  }
  
  // only run the function for the nextPlayer if the game didnt ended in a draw as otherwise the nextMove would update and overwrite the draw message
  if (currentTurn < 9 && !isWon) {
    nextPlayer();
  }
}



function AImove() {
  let unpickedCells = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i] === '') {
      unpickedCells.push(i);
    }
  }
  
  return (unpickedCells[Math.floor(Math.random() * unpickedCells.length)]);
}


function isWinner() {
  // even though that this is a constant, it is only relevant for that specific function and as such should be placed here. Later on important if you want to use modules
  const win = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i < win.length; i++) {
    const condition = win[i];
    const box1 = options[condition[0]];
    const box2 = options[condition[1]];
    const box3 = options[condition[2]];
    if (box1 === '' || box2 === '' || box3 === '') {
      continue;
    }
    if (box1 === box2 && box2 === box3) {
      isWon = true;
      boxs[condition[0]].classList.add('win');
      boxs[condition[1]].classList.add('win');
      boxs[condition[2]].classList.add('win');
    }
  }

  if (isWon || currentTurn === 9) {
    statusTxt.textContent = (isWon) ? `Player ${player} wins!!` : 'The Game is Tied';
    running = false;
    // disables all othe cells so they can't be when the game has ended.
    boxs.forEach(box => box.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true'));
    //stopCount();
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'DM Serif Display', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#timer {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#timeClock {
  text-align: center;
}

#pickGame {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#messageGame {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: blueviolet;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#status {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

button {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  border: 1px black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

button:active {
  background-color: salmon;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

/* this CSS line will disable pointer events preventing from a cell to be clicked if it is disabled. Works with screen readers too */
.box[aria-disabled="true"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.win {
  animation: winAnimation ease-in-out 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes winAnimation {
  0% {
    background-color: #7c74d4;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #d8d5f5;
  }
  0% {
    background-color: #7c74d4;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<h3>What kind of game do you want to play ?</h3><br>

<input type="radio" id="pvp" name="gameType" value="Player v Player" />Player v Player
<input type="radio" id="pvc" name="gameType" value="Player v Computer" />Player v Computer<br><br>
<button id="start" onclick="checkGameType()">START!</button>
<!--<button id="newGame" onclick="newGame()">New Game</button>-->

<div id="messageGame"></div><br>

<div>----[[Game Clock]]----</div>
<p id="timeClock"> </p>
<div id="status">Pick a game above and hit Start!</div>

<div class="container" id="board">
  <div data-index="0" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="1" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="2" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="3" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="4" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="5" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="6" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="7" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  <div data-index="8" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="restart" onclick="restartGame()">Restart</button>

<script src="pvpgame.js"></script>
```

I replaced `innerHTML` with `textContent` for performance (reparsing DOM) and security reasons (XSS).
If you still have questions about the logic or how your code was fixed, then feel free to ask!

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I appreciate the coding guidelines and how I can improve for the next project. I could not figure out what kind of loop would work for checking the empty boxes.